# Error inflating class it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cards

I'm trying to follow this example [cardslib example](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARDLIST.md) but I'm running into an exception which I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cards_teste, container, true);
//      CardView cardView = (CardView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cards_teste, container, false);
        ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

        //Create a Card
        Card card = new Card(getActivity());

        //Create a CardHeader
        CardHeader header = new CardHeader(getActivity());

        //Add Header to card
        card.addCardHeader(header);
        cards.add(card);

        CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getActivity(), cards);

        CardListView listView = (CardListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myList_teste);

        if (listView!=null)
        {
            listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
        }
//      return cardView;
        return view;
    }
}
```

And here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myList_teste"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367): Process: com.mypackage.android.design.appdesgin, PID: 3367
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at com.mypackage.android.design.appdesgin.fragments.FragmentA.onCreateView(FragmentA.java:23)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     ... 20 more
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.R$styleable
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView.initAttrs(CardListView.java:146)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView.init(CardListView.java:127)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView.<init>(CardListView.java:106)
06-05 23:26:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     ... 23 more
```

Can someone explain me why is the exception occurring and how to fix it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the method requested in the comments. What is between ** ** is the exact line

```
protected void initAttrs(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        list_card_layout_resourceID = R.layout.list_card_layout;

        TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                **attrs, R.styleable.card_options, defStyle, defStyle);**

        try {
            list_card_layout_resourceID = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.card_options_list_card_layout_resourceID, this.list_card_layout_resourceID);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: clean and build your project

Comment: `at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView.initAttrs(CardListView.java:146)` can you show us which line is this one?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin it didn't help, I cleaned and built my project to no success

Comment: perfect try this (change the `defStyle` by 0) , like this:  `TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.card_options, 0, 0);` .

Comment: @ahmed_khan_89 now I get this exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
` but I don't think I should be editing the library as it may fix this error but propagate a lot more errors in the future. It should work as it is in my opinion, therefore I believe the error is somewhere on my code and not the library's code

Comment: @ahmed_khan_89 it works as you suggested, nevermind that exception. That was me trying something else (I passed true to `attachToRoot` on the inflate method, with `false` it works but I don't feel comfortable changing the library code

Comment: I wanted to test it, to know the origin of the real error. so your principal error is : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` I will write you an answer.

Comment: @ahmed_khan_89 please check the comment above yours. That exception was me that forgot to pass `attachToRoot` as `false` in the inflate method. With `attachToRoot` as true no exception is generated and the layout is inflated successfully. But for that I've to set `defStyle` to zero in the library code, as your suggestion

Comment: Is there any Android card UI library which provides method for swapping between cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your principal error is : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

It is because you are trying to inflate the same `View` twice in the same `ViewGroup`.

If you want to inflate it again , you have to create a new instance, or give a new ID , or remove the old one...

OK , now when I am writing this , you fixed this bug saying in comments :

```
hat exception was me that forgot to pass attachToRoot as false in the inflate method. With attachToRoot as true no exception is generated and the layout is inflated successfully.
```

If you try to put again the `defStyle`, I think it would work.

Comment: Is there any Android card UI library which provides method for swapping between cards?